# Ros Noetic python3 - rqt cannot find my plugins

Tags: plugin, ros-noetic, qtcreator, rqt-gui, rqt-bag

I wanted to create my own rqt GUI to publish topic in ROS and incorporated it into my package.Although I have no problem implementing the catkin build package,
After running rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui, I get the following error as soon as I select my homebrew GUI from the menu plugin.

```
    PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "my_rqt_plugin/my_rqt_plugin":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 102, in load
    self._load()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 55, in _load
    self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui_py/ros_py_plugin_provider.py", line 61, in load
    return super(RosPyPluginProvider, self).load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 106, in load
    return class_ref(plugin_context)
  File "/home/User/catkin_ws/src/my_rqt_plugin/scripts/my_rqt_plugin/my_rqt_plugin.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._widget.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.publish)
```

By the way, the default plugins such as "Message Publisher" work as usual.
I am guessing that it is probably the interference between python2 and python3, but I have no idea how to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance for your help.

My package for my own GUI has the following file structure.

[image]

**[environment/library used]**

ubuntu20.04 ROS 1 noetic

pyQt 5

pyside6